Centos Samba Access to NTFS mounted drive...Access Denied
Noob here.  I am having a problem with accessing an NTFS drive mounted on a Centos 9   server.
I mounted it at /mnt/ntfs and configured a basic
open SAMBA server for testing purposes.
I can lock it down after I can see that there are no other
technical hurdles.  Below are the fstab entry and
the smb.conf files.  I am able to access it the
mount point using a regular centos user and
if I go one step up in the hierarchy I can see the
mount point when I use the guest SAMBA mapping in Windows 11.
    fstab
        /dev/sdc1               /mnt/ntfs               ntfs-3g defaults        0 0

    smb conf

    [global]
            workgroup = WORKGROUP
            map to guest = Bad User
            log file = /var/log/samba/%m
            log level = 1
            server role = standalone server

    [guest]
            path = /mnt
            read only = no
            guest ok = yes
            guest only = yes

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
I tried adding a symbolic link to a regular unix user and creating a share around that ID but the same result...Access Denied.`

Was able to resolve this issue by editing the /etc/selinux/config file and changing the SELINUX=enforced to SELINUX=permissive.  The symboic link that I created to point to the /mmt/ntfs point from the user's home directory is now able to be shared in SAMBA.

That is like saying "If you cannot get into your house, next time simply leave the door open." What you suggest fundamentally changes the security on the target system. It would be better to show how to adjust the SE-Linux context of the folder in question.

You are correct.  My next step is to lock the ntfs file system down so that the authorized users are the only ones who can access the ntfs drive.  With the default SELINUX value I could access all files under the user's home directory but not the symbolic link files even if the owner and group were the same as the home user's group.

We are talking of SELinux, which basically puts each process in its own context and uses xattrs to force additional checks beyond ownership. There are also some general boolean flags for common use cases. RedHat provides a good primer
